# Android - Cursor loop skips first row

Tags: android

What this code does is take every "Project" thats saved in the SQLite database and uploads it online to Parse.com

Please help me understand why this code doesnt upload the first entry. I believe i have the order mixed up somehow. It seems to only start at row 2 of the Cursor.

```
Cursor c = dbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
    String[] data;
    c.moveToFirst();
    if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message : " + c.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String s = c.getString(5);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date d = new Date();
            try {
                d = dateFormat.parse(s);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            data = new String[8];
            data[0] = c.getString(0);
            data[1] = c.getString(1);
            data[2] = c.getString(2);
            data[3] = c.getString(3);
            data[4] = c.getString(4);
            data[6] = c.getString(6);
            data[7] = c.getString(7);

            Project p1 = new Project(Integer.valueOf(data[0]), data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], d, data[6], data[7]);

            ParseObject p2 = new ParseObject("Project");
            p2.put("projectSubject", p1.getProjectSubject());
            p2.put("projectType", p1.getProjectType());
            p2.put("projectTitle", p1.getProjectTitle());
            p2.put("projectWorth", p1.getProjectWorth());
            p2.put("projectDueDate", p1.getProjectDueDate());
            p2.put("projectDetails", p1.getProjectDetails());
            p2.put("email", "chrismaher.wit@gmail.com");

            ///////////////////////////////////

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> querySubject = ParseQuery.getQuery("Project");
            querySubject.whereEqualTo("projectSubject", p1.getProjectSubject());

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryTitle = ParseQuery.getQuery("Project");
            queryTitle.whereEqualTo("projectTitle", p1.getProjectTitle());

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryDetails = ParseQuery.getQuery("Project");
            queryDetails.whereEqualTo("projectDetails", p1.getProjectDetails());

            List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
            queries.add(querySubject);
            queries.add(queryTitle);
            queries.add(queryDetails);

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
            mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {

                    listSize = list.size();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ListSize : " + listSize, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            if (listSize == 0) {

                p2.saveInBackground();

            }


        }
        c.close();
    }
```

Comment: As per what Guillaume says, you could use a do { } while(c.moveToNext()) instead of your while loop

Comment: Not even that. The while is relevant here, if there is no other test before

Comment: Actually Pol you are right if he wants to keep the moveToFirst instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.moveToFirst();
if (c != null) {
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
```

That's your problem

Comment: Thanks but what order should it be in?

Comment: Well, first of all checking for null after using the object is non-sense. after that, you should only not move 2 times, otherwise it's normal the first row is skipped

Comment: Just remove c.moveToFirst(); from your code and your should be fine.